# How do I open an RESP account where I am both the subscriber and the beneficiary?

Tags: canada, savings, education-savings, resp

I am located in Canada and am trying to open an RESP account where I am both the subscriber and the beneficiary. The government of Canada website says I can open an RESP for myself [here](https://www.canada.ca/en/employment-social-development/services/student-financial-aid/education-savings/resp/info.html). I’ve called the 3 biggest banks I could think of — RBC, TD and wealthsimple — but they won't allow me to list myself as a beneficiary. Does anyone have any idea how I can open an RESP account for myself where I am both the subscriber and the beneficiary?

Comment: What is your age and what is your Canadian residency status?

Comment: @MorrisonChang citizen and 19, I do also hold an RRSP and a TFSA at a Canadian bank

Comment: @MorrisonChang the banks i listed are willing to open an RESP for me, they just won't allow me to list myself as a benefactor.